# I want to send webcam video data in database on button click through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**index.php**

In this file I create webcam and create buttons record, save, stop.

```
    <html>
        <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#fff">
        <!--<base target="_blank">-->
        <title>Access Webcam Device</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="today/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    $sessData = !empty($_SESSION['sessData'])?$_SESSION['sessData']:'';
    if(!empty($sessData['status']['msg'])){
        $statusMsg = $sessData['status']['msg'];
        $statusMsgType = $sessData['status']['type'];
        unset($_SESSION['sessData']['status']);
    }
    ?>

        <?php
            if(!empty($sessData['userLoggedIn']) && !empty($sessData['userID'])){
                include 'user.php';
                $user = new User();
                $conditions['where'] = array(
                    'id' => $sessData['userID'],
                );
                $conditions['return_type'] = 'single';
                $userData = $user->getRows($conditions);
        ?>
        <div class="tech">
        <header>
           <h1>Header</h1>
           <div class="log"><span>Welcome <?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?>!</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="userAccount.php?logoutSubmit=1" class="logout">Logout</a></div>
        </header>
        <!--<div class="main">-->
        <div class="regisFrm">
            <!--<p><b>Name: </b><?php //echo $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Email: </b><?php //echo $userData['email']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Phone: </b><?php //echo $userData['phone']; ?></p>-->
            <div id="container">
                <div style = "text-align:center;">
                    <h1>Webcam Recorder </h1>

                    <video controls autoplay></video><br>
                    <button id="rec" onclick="onBtnRecordClicked()">Record</button>
                    <button id="pauseRes"   onclick="onPauseResumeClicked()" disabled>Pause</button>
                    <button id="stop"  onclick="onBtnStopClicked()" disabled>Stop</button>
                    <button id="saveBtn" >Save</button>
                 </div>
                <a id="downloadLink" download="mediarecorder.webm" name="mediarecorder.webm" href></a>
                <p id="data"></p>
                <script src="today/main.js"></script>
                <script src="today/jQuery2.1.1.min.js"></script>


             </div>
        </div>

        </div>


        <?php }else{ ?>

        <div class="tech">
        <header>
           <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="main">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background: #fff;color: #555;border: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="margin:10px 0; padding-left:10px;font-weight:bold;    font-size: 18px;">
        <i style="float:left;padding: 1px 6px 0 0;font-size: 16px;" class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                        Sign in</h3>
                        </div>

        <?php echo !empty($statusMsg)?'<p class="'.$statusMsgType.'">'.$statusMsg.'</p>':''; ?>
        <div class="regisFrm">
            <form action="userAccount.php" method="post" style="padding:10px 10px;">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required="">
                <div class="send-button">
                    <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="LOGIN">
                </div>
            </form>
            <p style="padding-left:10px;">Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php">Register</a></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <footer>Copyright &copy; </footer>
    </div>

    <script>
        function drawOnCanvas(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            var dataURL = e.target.result,
                c = document.querySelector('canvas'), // see Example 4
                ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
                img = new Image();

            img.onload = function() {
              c.width = img.width;
              c.height = img.height;
              ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };

            img.src = dataURL;
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**main.js**
in the above ajax i am doing access webcam video data and want to store data in database.

```
    'use strict';

    /* globals MediaRecorder */

    // Spec is at http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/media-stream-capture/RecordingProposal.html

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;


    if(getBrowser() == "Chrome"){
        var constraints = {"audio": true, "video": {  "mandatory": {  "minWidth": 640,  "maxWidth": 640, "minHeight": 480,"maxHeight": 480 }, "optional": [] } };//Chrome
    }else if(getBrowser() == "Firefox"){
        var constraints = {audio: true,video: {  width: { min: 640, ideal: 640, max: 640 },  height: { min: 480, ideal: 480, max: 480 }}}; //Firefox
    }

    var recBtn = document.querySelector('button#rec');
    var pauseResBtn = document.querySelector('button#pauseRes');
    var stopBtn = document.querySelector('button#stop');

    var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
    var dataElement = document.querySelector('#data');
    var downloadLink = document.querySelector('a#downloadLink');

    videoElement.controls = false;

    function errorCallback(error){
        console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);   
    }

    /*
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
    var sourceBuffer;
    */

    var mediaRecorder;
    var chunks = [];
    var count = 0;

    function startRecording(stream) {
        log('Start recording...');
        if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function'){
            /*
                MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported is a function announced in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder and later introduced in the MediaRecorder API spec http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/
            */
            if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
              var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
            } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=h264')) {
              var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};
            } else  if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
              var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
            }
            log('Using '+options.mimeType);
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        }else{
            log('Using default codecs for browser');
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        }

        pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";

        mediaRecorder.start(10);

        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        videoElement.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
        videoElement.play();

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            //log('Data available...');
            //console.log(e.data);
            //console.log(e.data.type);
            //console.log(e);
            chunks.push(e.data);
        };

        mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e){
            log('Error: ' + e);
            console.log('Error: ', e);
        };


        mediaRecorder.onstart = function(){
            log('Started & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
        };

        mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
            log('Stopped  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);

            var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "video/webm"});
            chunks = [];

            var videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            downloadLink.href = videoURL;
            videoElement.src = videoURL;
            downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download video file';

            var rand =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000));
            var name  = "video_"+rand+".webm" ;

            downloadLink.setAttribute( "download", name);
            downloadLink.setAttribute( "name", name);
            loadToServer(blob);
        };

        function loadToServer(blob){
        var data = new FormData();
          data.append('file', blob);
        debugger;
          $.ajax({
            url :  "recording.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data:data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              alert("boa!");
            },    
            error: function() {
              alert("not so boa!");
            }
          });
        }

        mediaRecorder.onpause = function(){
            log('Paused & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
        }

        mediaRecorder.onresume = function(){
            log('Resumed  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
        }

        mediaRecorder.onwarning = function(e){
            log('Warning: ' + e);
        };
    }

    //function handleSourceOpen(event) {
    //  console.log('MediaSource opened');
    //  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp9"');
    //  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
    //}

    function onBtnRecordClicked (){
         if (typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia) {
            alert('MediaRecorder not supported on your browser, use Firefox 30 or Chrome 49 instead.');
        }else {
            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, startRecording, errorCallback);
            recBtn.disabled = true;
            pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
            stopBtn.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function onBtnStopClicked(){
        debugger;
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        videoElement.controls = true;

        recBtn.disabled = false;
        pauseResBtn.disabled = true;
        stopBtn.disabled = true;
    }

    function onPauseResumeClicked(){
        if(pauseResBtn.textContent === "Pause"){
            console.log("pause");
            pauseResBtn.textContent = "Resume";
            mediaRecorder.pause();
            stopBtn.disabled = true;
        }else{
            console.log("resume");
            pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";
            mediaRecorder.resume();
            stopBtn.disabled = false;
        }
        recBtn.disabled = true;
        pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
    }


    function log(message){
        dataElement.innerHTML = dataElement.innerHTML+'<br>'+message ;
    }



    //browser ID
    function getBrowser(){
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browserName  = navigator.appName;
        var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
        var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

        // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
        if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
         browserName = "Opera";
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
         if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
           fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
        }
        // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
        else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
         browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
        }
        // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome"
        else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
         browserName = "Chrome";
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
        }
        // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"
        else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
         browserName = "Safari";
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
         if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
           fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
        }
        // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox"
        else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
         browserName = "Firefox";
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
        }
        // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent
        else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) <
               (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) )
        {
         browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
         fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
         if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
          browserName = navigator.appName;
         }
        }
        // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
        if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
           fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
        if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
           fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
         fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
         majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
        }


        return browserName;
    }
```

**recording.php**

This is my recording.php which is use for ajax in url, this is also a action in which i am try to store data in database behalf of this page.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('registered_users',$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql= "INSERT INTO recording (video_static.webm) VALUES ('".$_POST['file']."')";
//echo $sql;
mysql_query($sql);

header("location: index.php");  //link to redirect page 

}

?>
```

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Comment: Hello sir,I created my webcam and i want to save my webcam data in database in php, but data save into database  when i click on stop recording button.

Comment: Sir are you getting my question.

Comment: Hello sir,I created my webcam and i want to save my webcam data in database in php,  when i click on stop recording button.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You should store the video in the file system and store a link to the video in the database. It is very inefficient to stare BLOB's in the database.

Comment: thanks sir, but what is the process of store the video in the file system and store a link to the video in the database.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Ok sir, actually i don't  much knowledge of ajax and java script. that's why i stuck this task.

Comment: Stack is not here to write code for you, it is here to guide you when you have a problem.